# Atalho no Inicializar do usuário clickonce

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

Tenho um aplicativo `ClickOnce`, tenho a opção de criar um atalho no `Desktop`, mas existe uma forma de fazer que ele adicione um atalho no Inicializar do `Windows`? Programaticamente, que o usuário ao instalar o aplicativo, cria automaticamente o atalho?

Comment: Você quer que ele inicialize junto com o windows?

Comment: Isto, quero q ele inicialize junto com o Windows, mas quero fazer com programação..

Comment: Sem programação é impossível fazer

Comment: E que posso adixionar o atalho manualmente no inicializar

Comment: Então adicione manualmente.

Comment: Sim, vou passar as 500 máquinas e fazer manualmente!

Comment: Então vai ter que escrever algumas linhas de código, pode ser?

Comment: Sim, o que quero é que quando o usuário instalar o aplicativo já adicione o atalho automaticamente no inicializar..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Tem essas estratégias utilizadas aqui

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401816/how-can-i-make-a-click-once-deployed-app-run-at-startup

http://dipeshavlani.net/2009/05/12/clickonce-and-startup-on-windows-logon-vista/

http://www.brokenwire.net/bw/Programming/116/run-clickonce-app-on-startup

Comment: Obrigado, vou da uma olhada..